# having an issue with react-native expo build?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am creating a react-native expo app and i wanted to test it on my physical mobile which currently runs on Android Version 11.

the problem is i am following all the expo dcoumentation and step correctly to generate a preview build with apk, but i am getting the same problem every time.

**Problem:** Build is successfully done, and it is getting successfully installed on device & emulator but it is not opening it showing a flash screen and then closes automatically.

**What I have Done so far to reaolve the erro** =>
1). I've tested and analyzed apk in android studio and found out this error.

```
08/11 12:31:08: Launching 'new1_1' on Pixel 5 API 30.
Install successfully finished in 6 s 245 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.surajaswal29.myapp/com.surajaswal29.myapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 23870 on device 'Pixel_5_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ajaswal29.myap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.surajaswal29.myapp/lib-main
I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.surajaswal29.myapp/lib-main
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.surajaswal29.myapp/lib-main
V/SoLoader: Init SoLoader delegate
E/EmbeddedManifest: Could not read embedded manifest
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at expo.modules.updates.manifest.BareUpdateManifest$Companion.fromBareManifest(BareUpdateManifest.kt:97)
        at expo.modules.updates.manifest.ManifestFactory.getEmbeddedManifest(ManifestFactory.kt:36)
        at expo.modules.updates.manifest.EmbeddedManifest.get(EmbeddedManifest.kt:30)
        at expo.modules.updates.launcher.NoDatabaseLauncher.<init>(NoDatabaseLauncher.kt:70)
        at expo.modules.updates.launcher.NoDatabaseLauncher.<init>(NoDatabaseLauncher.kt:23)
        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController.start(UpdatesController.kt:243)
        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController$Companion.initialize(UpdatesController.kt:603)
        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesPackage$createReactNativeHostHandlers$handler$1.onWillCreateReactInstanceManager(UpdatesPackage.kt:56)
        at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:27)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
        at com.surajaswal29.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:71)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.surajaswal29.myapp, PID: 23870
    java.lang.AssertionError: The embedded manifest is invalid or could not be read. Make sure you have configured expo-updates correctly in android/app/build.gradle. null
        at expo.modules.updates.manifest.EmbeddedManifest.get(EmbeddedManifest.kt:34)
        at expo.modules.updates.launcher.NoDatabaseLauncher.<init>(NoDatabaseLauncher.kt:70)
        at expo.modules.updates.launcher.NoDatabaseLauncher.<init>(NoDatabaseLauncher.kt:23)
        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController.start(UpdatesController.kt:243)
        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController$Companion.initialize(UpdatesController.kt:603)
        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesPackage$createReactNativeHostHandlers$handler$1.onWillCreateReactInstanceManager(UpdatesPackage.kt:56)
        at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:27)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
        at com.surajaswal29.myapp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:71)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6712)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

2. My eas.json file

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

3. My app.json file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-updates",
        {
          "username": "surajaswal29"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.surajaswal29.myapp"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "c82a7215-d33d-44b9-90cb-15317f417dd4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4). Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.7",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.18.11",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```